# Can I reload a div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an area made up in a navigation by bar some PHP code that either shows a inline login form or the users username. The login form is submit using jQuery so no page load is required to set the users session variables etc. but how can I get around not having to refresh the page so that the correct text is shown (i.e. the users username rather than the inline form)?

At the moment the login works seamlessly without having to refresh the page but I need to somehow update that area also.

```
        <div id="divLogin">
        <?php if (!logged_in()) { ?>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="user">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" id="pass">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="login">Sign in</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="register">Register</button>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="form-group">
          <p>You are logged in as <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></strong></p>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: you have to update the div id="divLogin" using ajax. just after the login logic is finished.

Comment: You say "login works seamlessly without having to refresh the page". Are you using jQuery to effect this? If so can you add the code that does this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using load() function or by using AJAX.

```js
$('.your_button').on('click', function(){
     $('#divLogin').load('your_page_url_here');
});
```

Comment: Does the PHP get reloaded as if the user refreshes?

Comment: Yes, it does just that.

Comment: Can you provide example? Do I just do `$('#divLogin').load();` to just refresh the current contents?

Comment: Strange I keep getting the login form until I refresh browser, then I get the 'logged in as....'

Comment: I feel like this function doesn't do what the OP wants... I think you should really help him to write AJAX, right?

Comment: Just calling load() is not enough - you need to create a controller in your PHP code, which returns new html content of the div as AJAX response. You then map it to a URL (e.g. `http://localhost/loginFormSection.php`) and then use that url as first argument to load(), such as `$('#divLogin').load('http://localhost/loginFormSection.php');` Otherwise nothing is refreshed on your page until full page reload.